# Why can't I delete the contents of the 'INetCache' folder from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I'm using Windows 10 and need to update a batch file to clear the contents of folder at `"C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache"`. This is the folder that holds cache for Internet Explorer.

I would have thought the command was simply as follows:

```
DEL /S /F /Q C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\\*
```

This command executes without issue, but when I look at the contents of the folder via Windows Explorer, it still has stuff in it. I say "stuff" because while it looks like a bunch of files, they don't behave like typical files. For instance, I cannot see these files when when I use "dir" on the command prompt no matter which flags I utilize. And when I examine the properties of these files, there is barely any information associated with them.

Why isn't my DEL command clearing out these files?

[Screenshot of "files" still present in my INetCache folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uo3s.png)

[Screenshot of the properties of one of these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6crGU.png)

Comment: Doesn't the "Storage sense" feature do, what you are trying to imitate?

Answer (score 3):

I found that using the "rmdir" command instead of the "del" command resolved my issue.

```
rmdir "C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache" /s /q
```

Answer (score 0):

open txt and save .bat file

```
DEL /S /F /Q C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You may see your answer if you take out `/Q`. The reason you cannot delete the files is that they are being used by another process

Change:

From:

```
DEL /S /F /Q C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*
```

To:

```
DEL /S /F C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\*
```

The `/Q` flag in the original command is used to suppress the "Are you sure?" prompt when deleting files. However, by removing the `/Q` flag, the prompt will be shown before deletion, giving you a chance to see any error messages or understand why certain files cannot be deleted.

Additionally, the message explains that the reason for not being able to delete the files is that they are currently in use by another process.